# imageresizer 4.0.5 combined with servicestack blocking images

Tags: imageresizer

When requesting images on path site/image.jpg or site/image.jpg?process=no i only get a 404 while site/image.jpg?maxwidht=2000 works just fine.

removing the servicestack handler from web.config resolves the issue:

```
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
</handlers>
```

How can I make servicestack and imageresizer run together on IIS8?

Answer (score -1):

That configuration causes all requests to be given to ServiceStack, preventing middleware from working. It's a terrible practice if one values interoperability, and I'm suprised to see it.

Because if its location at the top of the queue, it is preventing the StaticFileModule & StaticFileHandler from handling static requests, yet failing to serve them itself.

1. You may want to install ImageResizer in a subfolder/sub application to avoid a conflict. [Example w/ service stack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework).
2. ImageResizer has a way to 'fixup' frameworks which don't handle VPPs correctly. In this case, static files aren't getting handled correctly, so the detection doesn't work. You can set `<pipeline vppUsage="Always" />` to force this code path.

Comment: No it's standard practice for web frameworks to handle all requests - that's what makes it work. You can also register handler mappings before the fallback mapping in addition to running multiple web frameworks together by registering them at different mappings as detailed in the document you linked.

Comment: ImageResizer works with over 35 different CMSes and web frameworks. "handle all requests" <- Sure, in the form of an HttpModule. HttpHandlers should be determined by HttpModules, *NEVER* by arbitrary handler mapping.  Also, a fallback mapping would be no problem. That is NOT a fallback mapping! It takes precedence over all other handlers installed. Get your facts straight. ASP.NET is a POS, but there are well known patterns to avoid the crappiest parts, and 99% of frameworks get it right in 2016. (not many did in 2007, though).

Comment: And? is there a point to this factoid? Is it an actual Web Framework? Can it handle default document Razor Views? pre-process markdown docs? assert custom request validation on static requests, minify all html/js/css static resources at runtime? transparently serve embedded resources, etc. i.e. do things Web Frameworks need to do - if you looked at how alternative Web Frameworks worked you'll notice they support a wild card mapping as well.

Comment: You're speaking from ignorance and inexperience, the using a HttpHandler is the cleanest way to allow web frameworks to be mapped at different API's. HTTP Modules are a global and ugly hack to support this which is why most alternative ASP.NET web frameworks don't use it. Your invalid and presumptuous assertion that "99% of frameworks get it right in 2016" is completely wrong and inexperienced.

Comment: Sure, if you want to fully replace ASP.NET's crap and prohibit generic middleware and HttpModules. But there's no way in hell I'm going to port ImageResizer to ServiceStack's custom architecture. I'll port ImageResizer once more, and to OWIN. I'm not attacking your choices overall, just in the context of being middleware-friendly. And some middleware can still work with that design, but ImageResizer 4 integrates deeply with IIS for fast cache hit performance.

Comment: Going to let this slide -> `You're speaking from ignorance and inexperience`.

Comment: WTF? HttpHandlers don't need to know anything about ServiceStack, it's custom architecture or any other HttpHandlers. The point of handlers is that  they can be completely isolated, registered at different mappings in the order they want registered. Good luck if you think OWIN is the future, IMO you'd be better off registering a native CoreCLR handler instead.

Comment: Isolation isn't always what you want, particularly if you want an efficient handoff from managed to native code. We abandoned that approach in 2008 after extended discussions with the IIS team and a comprehensive review of the managed and native codebase handling the Integrated and Classic pipelines. We were targeting petabyte image sets, so there were different design criteria at play.

Comment: So then how are the additional managed abstraction layers added by OWIN more efficient than registering a HttpHandler directly?

Comment: Have you seen the OWIN SendFile spec?

Comment: No what's a spec going to do? It's not going to be faster than TransmitFile(), it looks like it's just an abstraction over [writing the FileStream to the ResponseStream](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/SendFileMiddleware.cs).